# How to: generic that accepts readonly types?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

Given an action on a list

```
type DoSomethingWith<L extends any[]> = L
```

what i'm trying to do works as such

```
const keys = {
  a: ['a', 'b', 'c'] as ['a', 'b', 'c'],
  d: ['d', 'e', 'f'] as ['d', 'e', 'f'],
}

type Keys = typeof keys

type KeysWithSomething = {
  [K in keyof Keys]: DoSomethingWith<Keys[K]>
}
```

But to avoid redunduncy (on what could possibly be longer list) i wish to be able to write it as such:

```
const keys = {
  a: ['a', 'b', 'c'] as const,
  d: ['d', 'e', 'f'] as const,
}

type Keys = typeof keys

type DoSomethingWith<L extends any[]> = L

type KeyKinds = {
  [K in keyof Keys]: DoSomethingWith<Keys[K]>
                                  // ^^^^^^^: Type '{ a: readonly ["a", "b", "c"]; d: readonly ["d", "e", "f"]; }[K]' does not satisfy the constraint 'any[]'.
}
```

The error is that i try to pass a readonly type on `DoSomething` with which expect a generic list type (`any[]`)
Is they're a way to specify to `DoSomething` that it should accepts readonly element as well?

Comment: `type DoSomethingWith<L extends readonly any[]> = L`

Comment: Thank you @ford04 - might i ask how it can accepts both readonly and not readonly types as parameters ?

Comment: Should have tried before - works juste fine - can you post an answer so I can validates it @ford04 ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you can use the `readonly` modifier in a generic constraint:

```
type DoSomethingWith<L extends readonly any[]> = L
//                             ^ add this
```

Or you go the other way round and remove the `readonly` flag, after having narrowed `keys` with `as const`:

```
type Mutable<T> = T extends object ? { -readonly [K in keyof T]: Mutable<T[K]> } : T
```

Test with your types ([Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=16&ssc=2&pln=1&pc=1#code/MYewdgzgLgBA1gUwJ4RgXhgbwLACgYEwCGAXDANoDkRlANDJQEZ0PCUC6tehMAJmVV4tKCYQDMOXXAF9iqUJCh48UJAAcEMANLJUGVRpBj4u5bgOaAIiADKIALYIoACwCWYAOYB1Vy4A8ADIwCAAeUAhgvKhEYEjk7AB86DABZhYwALIArlBEjAA2CH4AKkkYxcFhEVEwIIwAVgjAsAD8WDAAtABOCES84PlIFFow7iZIRjDF7GTZuQVFxeRaiTCyZMVp6prFAIzJc3mFfjooSQD05+2kFABERLf0t4yPMLfAt+wA3HwCt7yvW4IQFiT4-aRbDTaZBadw1DA4fCEZajMDjSanCAzGDWOyOFzuby+Zx+Q4LE66ZaJBJ4aRAA)):

```
type T1 = Mutable<Keys> // { a: ["a", "b", "c"]; d: ["d", "e", "f"]; }

type KeyKinds = {
    [K in keyof Keys]: DoSomethingWith<Mutable<Keys[K]>> // compiles now
}
```